# What's the performance cost of using Cobertura to create system test coverage reports?

Tags: code-coverage, cobertura

I want to instrument my entire application, launch it, and then execute some system test runs. How much slower will my application run (manually testing so no ant JVM launch issues)?  1.5X, 2X, 10X, 20X,...

Answer (score 0):

The following studies show Cobertura adds from 30% to 100% to execution time.

Article: [Pick your code coverage tool in sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/pick-your-code-coverage-tool-in-sonar-2-2/)

Article: [Code coverage tools jacoco, cobertura, and emma. A comparison in sonar.](http://onlysoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/code-coverage-tools-jacoco-cobertura-emma-comparison-in-sonar/)